# $_SESSION is not retaining data - PHP

Tags: php, session

I've used session vars multiple times in the past, with no problems, but now it's got me...

The `$_SESSION` var I am setting is becoming unset every time the PHP script is fired, although it is setting ok for one variable at a time.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['badList'])) {
    print 'not set - again?';
    $_SESSION['badList'][0] = $lineNum;
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['badList'][count($_SESSION)] = $lineNum;
}
```

Here 'not set - again?' fires every time I perform the suitable action, i.e. PHP is not able to find the initial session var. The session cache seems to clear completely when a script is run, which sort of ruins the point of sessions.

What can I do? Many thanks.

Comment: Have you called `session_start()`?

Comment: Yes have done that... of course. I have uses Sessions before like I said

Comment: made sure the path in `session_save_path()` is writeable? and that the session cookie is being set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure you've called `session_start()`,  `/etc/php.ini` (or system equivalent) has a `session.save_path` set (ususally `/var/lib/php/session/`) and that directory is writable by your web server (on Linux it should be `drwxrwx---`) and that your disk is not full. If your sessions are being written to a remote store (database, memcached etc) make sure you can connect to that with the credentials your app uses (if applicable).

**edit:** also ensure you are calling [`session_write_close()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) at the end of your request - if you don't then the session data may not be written

Comment: Depends on your installation - try `locate php.ini`

Comment: or check `phpinfo()` which gives you the path as well, if you don't have shell access

Comment: I'm using the default MAMP set-up... it should work by default of course. I'm having major trouble changing `php.ini.default`... OSX refuses to allow. Just checked the php info and sessions is set ok...

Comment: I've done all that you suggested and the $_SESSION var is not getting recognised using `isset()` ever. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Realised I need to put session_start() in each script... oops!

Comment: @Andy, +1, Thanks for info on session.save_path. Just what I needed to solve the problem.